# Android Eclipse - Selected Item on Listview looses his Backgroundcolor when update Listview

Tags: android, listview, colors

After days of try and error, I have to ask you for help.

I have an Activity with a Listview and one Button. When I select an Item on the Listview the Color changes. Everything is fine. When I press the Button the selected Item to update his value.. that works fine too, BUT the selected color from the listview item disappear. I want that keep color on the item when I update the listview with:

> "list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,data));"

Here is my complete code from that Activity:
`public class AllActivity extends Activity {

```
int i;

ListView list;

ArrayList<String> data;

int index;

int top;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


setContentView(R.layout.activity_all);

list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_select2);

DatabaseCounter db = new DatabaseCounter(this);

ArrayList<Counter> counterList = db.getAllCounters();

data = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Counter counter : counterList){

    data.add(counter.getCounterName() + " : " + String.valueOf(counter.getCount()));

}

list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,data));

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        i = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id));

        index = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        View v = list.getChildAt(0);

        top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();


        for (int j = 0; j < parent.getChildCount(); j++)

            parent.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);


    }

});
```

}

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DatabaseCounter db = new DatabaseCounter(this);


    Counter counter;

    switch(v.getId()){


    case R.id.btn2_plus:


        counter = db.getCounter(i+1);

        counter.setCount(counter.getCount()+counter.getIncValue());

        db.updateCounter(counter);

        data.set(i, counter.getCounterName() + " : " + String.valueOf(counter.getCount()));

        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,data));

        list.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

        list.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);



        break;

    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: `When I select an Item on the Listview the Color changes.` ? Do you mean `When I click an Item on the Listview I change the Color.` ? `BUT the selected color from the listview item dissappear` Ok. But you forgot to tell when.

Answer (score 0):

nIf you want to have a permanet color for a list item view then you should not only put that color in on click but also tell your adapter that this item should have that color. When the user scrolls the list views get out of sight. When the view comes back the color has gone. You have to set the color again in getView(). For that to work you have to add another color or boolean array to your adaptor. In onclick set the right value for that the item on that position.